# How to read a CELLTYPE_NUMBER type cell as a string by using the LibXL, so that the string is the same as what is displayed?

Tags: libxl

The readStr function returns an empty string, and there are multiple types of numbers, such as NUMFORMAT_GENERAL, NUMFORMAT_NUMBER, NUMFORMAT_NUMBER_D2, NUMFORMAT_NUMBER_SEP, etc. I just want to get a string that looks the same as what is displayed.

The num may be display as:
1.1
1.11
1.111
1.025
$1.25
(4.25)

https://www.libxl.com/format.html

Thers is too many type.

switch (format->numFormat()) {
case NUMFORMAT_GENERAL:
case NUMFORMAT_NUMBER:
str = format->formatNumber(value, -1);
break;
case NUMFORMAT_NUMBER_D2:
str = format->formatNumber(value, 2);
break;
case NUMFORMAT_NUMBER_SEP:
str = format->formatNumber(value, -1);
str = str.replace(str.find_first_of(L'.'), 1, 1, L',');
break;
// other
default:
break;
}